# why when I enter matching array numbers they don't match array

Tags: javascript

I have created a lottery guessing game. The user will try to guess the winning numbers by entering 6 numbers into a prompt. If  the user guess all 6 number correctly, an alert box will display saying "Congratulations you're rich". However, I keep getting the Sorry play again message when I enter all the 6 numbers correct. What I am  I doing wrong? Thank you, I'm teaching myself to code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Winning lottery numbers</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

var GuessNum = []; 
GuessNum.join(', ');
var winningNumbers = [1, 19, 25, 27, 68, 21];
winningNumbers.join(', ');

for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {              
  GuessNum.push(prompt('Enter loto numbers ' + (i+1))); 
}

if(winningNumbers.includes(GuessNum)) {
    alert("Congratulations you're rich");
} else {
    alert("Sorry play again");
}


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can try adding a separate function to compare the array values. I've provided an answer, give it a try and see.

Comment: You are coming an int to an array. basically the includes will for each position compare the value to GuessNum (if [1,19,25,27,68,21] == 1), you will need to iterate over the values in each array (nested for loops).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code was that when you were doing `.includes()`, you were passing the whole array into it. Since `winningNumbers` does not include a full array, it would be false.

Anyways. To solve your problem, you would need a [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) loop to loop through `winningNumbers` and check if `GuessNum` contains the value.

You must do `e.toString()` because the result from a `prompt` is a string, so although all the numbers may be the same, one's a string and one's an integer.

```js
var GuessNum = []; 
GuessNum.join(', ');
var winningNumbers = [1, 19, 25, 27, 68, 21];
winningNumbers.join(', ');
var sameArray = true;

for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {              
  GuessNum.push(prompt('Enter loto numbers ' + (i+1))); 
}

winningNumbers.forEach(e => {
  if (!GuessNum.includes(e.toString())) {
    sameArray = false;
  }
});

if(sameArray) {
    alert("Congratulations you're rich");
} else {
    alert("Sorry play again");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, I have been struggling with this code for days.  Thank you to ever body for the help.

Comment: Your welcome. I'm always glad to help. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a array comparison function.

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gfktoaL0/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Winning lottery numbers</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

var GuessNum = []; 
GuessNum.join(', ');
var winningNumbers = [1, 19, 25, 27, 68, 21];
winningNumbers.join(', ');

for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {              
  GuessNum.push(prompt('Enter loto numbers ' + (i+1))); 
}

if(arraysEqual(GuessNum,winningNumbers)) {
    alert("Congratulations you're rich");
} else {
    alert("Sorry play again");
}

function arraysEqual(arr1, arr2) {
    if(arr1.length !== arr2.length)
        return false;
    for(var i = arr1.length; i--;) {
        if(arr1[i].toString() !== arr2[i].toString())
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're dealing with an array of integers, you can just sort them then convert to string to compare if they are equal.

```js
var guessNum = []; 
var winningNumbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {              
  guessNum.push(prompt('Enter loto numbers ' + (i+1))); 
}

if(guessNum.sort().toString() === winningNumbers.sort().toString()) {
    alert("Congratulations you're rich");
} else {
    alert("Sorry play again");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Winning lottery numbers</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem in `includes()` menthod:

The includes() method determines whether an array includes a certain value among its entries, returning true or false as appropriate.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes